# Taylor expansion of the power of fraction

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am stucked on the quite simple Taylor expansion of the following,
$$\left(\frac{z-a}{1-bz}\right)^n,$$
where $n$ is natural, $0<a<1$ and $0<b<1$. I would like to expand this near $z=0$. I write for the numerator
$$(z-a)^n=(-a)^n\sum_{j=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}n \\ j\end{pmatrix}(-1)^ja^{-j}z^j,$$
then I write for the denominator,
$$(1-bz)^{-n}=\sum_{k=}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix}-n \\ k\end{pmatrix}(-1)^kb^kz^k,$$
so finally I obtain
$$\left(\frac{z-a}{1-bz}\right)^n=(-a)^n\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix}n \\ j\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-n \\ k\end{pmatrix}(-1)^{j+k}a^{-j}b^kz^{k+j}.$$
It seems quite ugly and I would like to simplify it as most as possible. I have tried some manipulations with binomial coefficient product, then have tried to extract $n=0$ and $j=0$ terms, but have not succeeded in simplification. Could anyone give a tip what should I do?

Comment: Taylor expansion is essentially the differentiation (of all orders) of the function you are expanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left ( \frac{z - a}{1 - bz} \right )^n = (z - a)^n \left( \frac{1}{1 - bz} \right )^n$. Observe that for $|z| < 1$, $\left( \frac{1}{1 - bz} \right ) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (bz)^k$. Take the derivative of both sides $n$ times (using properties of convergent Taylor series to easily differentiate the right hand side) to obtain a Taylor series expansion for $\left ( \frac{1}{1 - bz} \right )^n$. Now multiply through by $(z - a)^n$.

Note that since we started with the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1 - bz}$ centered at $0$, the final Taylor series will also be centered at $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have completely forgotten about this